# Did Locke reject the idea that people had temporal parts?

Tags: metaphysics, identity, locke

I'm currently studying Locke's theory of personal identity and wondered if his writing rejected the idea that people had [temporal parts](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/temporal-parts/#9).

Does anyone have any references that would support the idea that Locke assumed people did not have temporal parts?

Comment: What have you come across so far in your own research? What reason(s) do you have to suspect that Locke might have held a particular position on this issue? More generally, showing some evidence of prior research will not only improve your question, but also increase the chances of getting upvotes and high-quality answers from our expert users.

Answer (score 1):

See §78, [**Reasons and Persons**](http://books.google.de/books?id=i5wQaJI3668C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Reasons+and+Persons+Derek+Parfit&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0PfKUN-iAoqQtAaNsoDoDg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Derek Parfit.

He discusses Locke's views on experience-memory as a criterion for identity's persistence over time to some length.